# Проверка транскрибирования

Tags: транскрипция

*Я подымаюсь по белой дороге пыльной, звенящей, крутой.

Не устают мои лёгкие ноги выситься над высотой.

Вижу его на дороге и в гроте...смуглую руку у лба...

Точно стеклянная, на повороте продребезжала арба...*

//jа пъдымаиус’ п^б’элъи д^рогъ/пыл’нъи/звинящиэй/крутоjй//
ниустъjут м^и лех’киъ ноги высиц^ нат высътоjй//
 //вижу иэво н^д^роги иф грот’ь//смуглуjу руку улбъ//
точнъ стиклянъjа /н^п^въротъ пр^дрибижалъ ^рба//

Answer (score 1):

//jа пъдымаjус’ пъб’элъй дърог'ь/пыл’нъй/зв'и(э)н'aш'(знак долготы)ьй/крутой// ньуст^jут м^и л'ох’к'иjь ног'и выс'ицъ нъдвыс^той// //в'ижу и(э)во нъд^рог'ь 
ивгрот’ь//смуглуjу руку улбъ// точнъ с'т'и(э)кл'aнъjь /нъпъв^рот'ь пръдр'ьб'и(э)жалъ ^рба//

Comment: улбъ
нъпъв^рот'ь
пръдр'ьб'и(э)жалъ

Comment: Согласна со всем, Людмила, кроме трёх слов.  Под ударением звучит чистый гласный, а стихотворный размер, насколько я поняла, - дактиль (с ударением на первом слоге). Поэтому  улба - с последним ударным А, напъв^рот'ь - после Н -  А (а не редуцированный  ъ), пръдр'ьб'и(э)жалъ - после Р -  тоже А